# Failed to find style 'listMenuViewStyle' in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-styles

I'm trying to add icons to my menu items in my android application. However the layout preview window in Android studio is displaying the error:

```
Failed to find style 'listMenuViewStyle' in current theme
```

I'm using the Holo.Light theme, and have tried a number of other themes with no luck. My layout xml is as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.me.myApp.activities.StartActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_section_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:title="@string/menu_section_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute `listMenuViewStyle` [was introduced with api level 24](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/24/changes/android.R.attr.html#android.R.attr.listMenuViewStyle). Make sure you use `compileSdkVersion 24` or above.

Comment: Thanks for the info!